# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store:

Tags: php, magento

I have my magento ecommerce website hosted on Godaddy. It is version 1.9.2.2. I attempted to restore a database backup but I got a 503 service unavailable error. So I decided to attempt the entire files backup. In the process I got a system and an exception error below. I am not sure whether the site broke when I attempted the database restore or the files restore.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in /home/tre76767667/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 645 and defined in /home/tre76767667/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:453 
Stack trace:
 #0 /home/tre76767667/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(645): Mage_Core_Model_Store->setWebsite(NULL)
 #1 /home/tre76767667/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(477): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
 #2 /home/tre76767667/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
 #3 /home/tre76767667/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 #4 /home/tre76767667/public_html/index.php(68): Mage::run('', 'store')
 #5 {main} thrown in /home/tre76767667/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php on line 453
```

In the error_log I got this:

```
[11-Dec-2019 21:09:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME in /home/tre76767667/public_html/cron.php on line 40
[11-Dec-2019 21:09:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME in /home/tre76767667/public_html/cron.php on line 41
```

Please can someone help me with how I can solve this?

Comment: PHP is getting more strict with OOP. You either have to downgrade to php 7.1 or 7.0 ish. Or look where the method Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite is defined and remove the argument type 'Mage_Core_Model_Website' or add a '?' before it. It also looks like it's trying to set a website adding the store website may fix it.

Comment: Thanks @KubwimanaAdrien. I did as you suggested by removing the argument type. However, I am getting this error in error_log: 
"[13-Dec-2019 00:19:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME in /home/tre76767667/public_html/cron.php on line 40
[13-Dec-2019 00:19:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME in /home/tre76767667/public_html/cron.php on line 41." Please you have any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: I am assuming the cron.php has the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and you're running the cron through server's crontab/cli where `$_SERVER` is not available. You'll need to check script name differently with something like `__FILE__`

Comment: Please how can I use __FILE__? What should I replace __FILE__ with? After that should I still go ahead to set the cron job? What I did as per some advice I saw online include: setting $isShellDisabled = true in cron.php; setting the cron job using Command: wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/PATH_TO_MAGENTO/cron.php > /dev/null; Thanks.

Comment: It's better to see the code in order to fix this right but try this. Replace `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` with `'/cron.php'` and replace `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` with `__FILE__` from `cron.php` .